# Nginx : blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I needs to enable cors policy to reach to my api, i did the following configuration on my nginx server file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name api.domain.com;

    location / {

       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://my_ip:6869/;

        set $ref "*";
        if ($http_referer ~* ^(http?\:\/\/)(.*?)\/(.*)$) {
          set $ref $1$2;
        }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $ref always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,signature,timestamp' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;

    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

But i keep getting the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.domain.com/data/key?matches=^art(.*)' from origin 'http://localhost:3500' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:3500', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

It seem that the add_header is adding on top of an already set header for Access-Control-Allow-Origin * but i only have this config file and don't see anywhere else where it could come from.

Is there a way to figure out what is setting the initial header cors policy or simply override it instead of adding to it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you haven't set up CORS configuration correctly.
you can fix this on you'r local machine using a plugin/extension called Allow-Control-Allow-Origin and add you'r localhost into it.

The other way is to manually fix the configuration in server side.

if you are not familiar with CORS it basically used to allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others. For example, if a site offers an embeddable service, it may be necessary to relax certain restrictions.

**Update**

Which compiler are you using for Nginx? If it's [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) one the following code must fix it:

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes i understant the purpose of CORS but i needs to fix that server side, not with browser plugin since the calls are done from another of my webapp in a server, can't ask everyone to use a plugin to access. What i don't get is where this initial allow origin come from, its not in my server file and it seem to be the problem since it end up with multiple value '*' and http://localhost:3500 where i needs it to be only http://localhost:3500

Comment: funny i had the same problem a few weeks back but i wasn't using Nginx.I managed to fixed it but never quite figured out the problem.I think it had to do with me changing the IPs of server/client(I had a test version and a production version and i recklessly switched between them sometimes i forgot to change them).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm not using a compiler, i mean i use the regular nginx package, i didn't compile anything. I'm considering to compile one to use this module: [link](https://webinoly.com/support/170/how-to-active-headers-more-nginx-module-in-nginx) that i guess would allow me to override the header with more_set_header but was hoping to figure out the problem without having to compile and use a 3rd party module.

Comment: @Christophe Good luck!

Comment: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: this only work for urls ending with eot|ttf|woff|woff2 ? I tried location ~* . to match anything but it does not work. I do not understand what does ~* mean, can you explain?